# How to avoid duplicate entries in Acumatica grid both on the screen and import scenario

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have a custom screen both form and grid, when user selects same value in grid it is allowing to save the record, but in my case it should not allow to insert same record in the grid also when user insert/update a record through import scenario it should behave same.

For example:

[image: Screenshot]

Below is the code

```
 public class KWStoreTrafficEntityMaint : PXGraph<KWStoreTrafficEntityMaint, KWStoreTrafficEntity>
    {
        public PXSelect<KWStoreTrafficEntity> Document;

        [PXImport(typeof(KWStoreTrafficEntity))]
        public PXSelect<KWStoreTrafficEntityDetails, Where<KWStoreTrafficEntityDetails.entityNbr,
            Equal<Current<KWStoreTrafficEntity.entityNbr>>>, OrderBy<Asc<KWStoreTrafficEntityDetails.sortOrder>>> Transactions;

            #region Event Handlers

             protected virtual void KWStoreTrafficEntityDetails_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            KWStoreTrafficEntityDetails items = e.Row as KWStoreTrafficEntityDetails;

            if (items == null)
                return;

            if (items.Period == "9 AM")
                items.SortOrder = 1;
            else if (items.Period == "10 AM")
                items.SortOrder = 2;
            else if (items.Period == "11 AM")
                items.SortOrder = 3;
            else if (items.Period == "12 PM")
                items.SortOrder = 4;
            else if (items.Period == "1 PM")
                items.SortOrder = 5;
            else if (items.Period == "2 PM")
                items.SortOrder = 6;
            else if (items.Period == "3 PM")
                items.SortOrder = 7;
            else if (items.Period == "4 PM")
                items.SortOrder = 8;
            else if (items.Period == "5 PM")
                items.SortOrder = 9;
            else if (items.Period == "6 PM")
                items.SortOrder = 10;
            else if (items.Period == "7 PM")
                items.SortOrder = 11;
        }
        protected virtual void KWStoreTrafficEntity_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
        {
            KWStoreTrafficEntity row = e.Row as KWStoreTrafficEntity;

            if (row == null)
                return;

            if(this.IsImport)
            {
                if (row.EntityDate == null)
                    return;

                foreach(KWStoreTrafficEntityDetails items in this.Transactions.Cache.Cached)
                {
                    PXTrace.WriteInformation(items.Period);
                }
            }

            if ((this.Document.Cache.GetStatus(this.Document.Current) == PXEntryStatus.Inserted || this.Document.Cache.GetStatus(this.Document.Current) == PXEntryStatus.Updated))
            {
                decimal? total = default(decimal);

                foreach (KWStoreTrafficEntityDetails items in this.Transactions.Select())
                {
                    total = total + items.TotalVisitors;                    
                }

                row.TotalVisitors = total;
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the field that should be unique (to avoid duplicates) declare it as a key field in database and in Acumatica DAC.

In the database, make sure the database field is declared as a unique key field:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-ver15

In Acumatica DAC use the IsKey=True property to indicate it's a unique key field:
https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=cef47ebf-cb3f-41dd-a137-be0201c84140